# How to create an action to copy a text layer across documents?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6, actions

In PS CS6, I am trying to create an action to copy a text layer from one document to another document to sit in the same location. Document size are same each other.

I couldn't find a way how to insert that copy command into the action.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `Layer > Duplicate Layer` (or right-click on the layer in the layer palette) does this by default, just select the document you want to copy the (text) layer to, and it pastes it in place.

You could create an action to bring up the dialog, but you'd probably want to input the second file each time - that would prevent it from being a one-click solution.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than thinking strictly "copy" or "duplicate" here's an alternative solution:

Open a document you want the text applied to, then start recording an action.

Now follow all the steps you need to to get the text to look how you want and to get it where you want.

Then stop recording the action.

Now simply call that action in any of your other documents and the action will recreate it exactly as before, essentially duplicating it.